# Calculate lines of code with git log additions and deletions

Tags: git

I want to work with the growth of files on git, so I need the lines of code for each file at a specific date.

Is there a possibility to calculate the lines of code for each file from the output of `git log --numstat --no-renames`. I know the solution with `wc -l` but that isn't what I need.
I tested it but I always get negative files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a diff against an [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309):

```
git diff --stat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 <aCommit>
```

For a given commit, you will get the list of files and their number of lines.